# Detect first key-down event only in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

In the `KeyboardEvent` object I get on key-down events, is there a way to know if the event is the first key-down, or a repeat when the key is held down?
I want to toggle a setting when a key is pressed; I could listen to key-up but I'd prefer the action is taken as soon as the key is pushed... as long as I can stop it toggling back and forth as the key-down repeat events are generated.

Answer (score 8):

Tested and works

```
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onUp);

var keys:Object = {};

function onDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if( ! Boolean(e.keyCode in keys)) {
        trace("First Time");        
        keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    }       
}

function onUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    delete keys[e.keyCode];
}
```

The idea of storing key codes in an object and the use of delete on key up originally came from Senoculars library. See http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript/

Comment: This is an obvious approach but kind of ugly. I wish the event simply stored this information, I _think_ Win32 does which is probably why I expected there to be a way.

Comment: Cool, it's a good idea to use a Dictionnay here instead of a mundane Object.
var keys:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

Comment: You could use a Dictionary for sure. The only thing is you wouldn't be leveraging any of the dictionary functionality, such as it's methods. Otherwise I agree

Answer (score 3):

The easiest thing is to remove or disable the `KEY_DOWN` listener with a flag inside the `KEY_DOWN` listener, and then add or enable it in the `KEY_UP`.

Comment: That would disable all key-down tracking though, what if another key gets pressed while it is down? In practice for a button you're supposed to tap, maybe this wouldn't be a problem... might be a neater approach.

Comment: Yes, you are correct.  That is where a solution like @Chris gave comes into play.  You really need to tailor this for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

private function onKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
    {

        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

    }
}

private function onKeyUp(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    if (event.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)

        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

        stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyUp);

    }
}
```