# Animation stop actionscript 3.0 tick

Tags: actionscript-3, animation

So, I have this game and I want the player to move, so I use a tick method when the key is down it creates 2 event listeners, a keyup listener and a tick.The keyup listener removes its self and removes the tick.The tick contains the movement and where I presumed the animation.
Here is my code:

```
// For every frame //
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
var gravity = 0.6;
var floor = 410;
jordan1.y = floor;
jordan1.speedY = floor;
jordan1.impulsion = 10;
var onFloor:Boolean = false;
var keyRight:Boolean = false;
stage.addChild(jordan1);
stage.addChild(leftwall1);
stage.addChild(finish1);
stage.addChildAt(abovedoor, 0);
stage.addChild(left);
stage.addChild(right);
stage.addChild(jump);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enters);
function enters(e:Event) {
    jordan1.speedY += gravity;
    jordan1.y += jordan1.speedY
    if(jordan1.y > floor) {
        jordan1.speedY = 0;
        jordan1.y = floor;
        onFloor = true;
        if(keyRight == true) {
            jordan1.gotoAndPlay(7);
        }
        if(keyRight == false) {
        jordan1.gotoAndStop(1);
        }
    }
}

function stageup(e:MouseEvent) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tickleft);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tickright);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageup);
}
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, stagedown);
function stagedown(e:MouseEvent) {
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stageup); 
}



stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, jumpkey);
function jumpkey(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE) {
       if(onFloor == true)
       {
        jordan1.speedY=-jordan1.impulsion;
        onFloor = false;
        jordan1.gotoAndStop(2);
       }
       }
    }

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, leftkey);
function leftkey(e:KeyboardEvent) {
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leftkeytick);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, leftkeydown);



}
}
function leftkeydown(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leftkeytick);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, leftkeydown);

}
function leftkeytick(e:Event) {
    jordan1.x-=10;
        if(onFloor == true) {
    jordan1.gotoAndStop(3);
    }
    if(onFloor == false) {
        jordan1.gotoAndStop(6);
    }

}





stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, rightkey);
function rightkey(e:KeyboardEvent) {
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
    keyRight == true;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rightkeytick);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, rightkeydown);
}
}
function rightkeydown(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rightkeytick);
    keyRight == false;
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, rightkeydown);
}
function rightkeytick(e:Event) {
    jordan1.x+=10;
    if(onFloor == true) {
    jordan1.gotoAndPlay(7);
    }
    if(onFloor == false) {
        jordan1.gotoAndStop(5);
    }
}

// Just for this frame //
leftwall1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, leftwall1hit);
function leftwall1hit(e:Event) {
    if(leftwall1.hitTestObject(jordan1)) {
        jordan1.x +=10;
    }
}

abovedoor.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, abovedoorhit);
function abovedoorhit(e:Event) {
    if(abovedoor.hitTestObject(jordan1)) {
        jordan1.x-=10;
    }
}

jordan1.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, finish1hit);
function finish1hit(e:Event) {
    if(jordan1.x > 960) {
        gotoAndStop(67);

    }
}
```

So, when I test it and put the keydown it goestoandstops at 7, instead of playing.Please help! Thank you!

Comment: You should reorganize your code to have only one `KEY_DOWN` listener and only one `ENTER_FRAME` listener. `KEY_DOWN` and `ENTER_FRAME` shouldn't call "one-called" function like `gotoAndPlay` or you'll end with calling this at each frame and never see the `Play` part.

Answer (score 0):

Your `goto` shouldn't be in your tick, or they will be executed each frame. Which explain why it's staying on frame 7.

Instead put them in your `KEY_DOWN`listener :

```
animated = false;
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, rightkey);
function rightkey(e:KeyboardEvent) {
  if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
    if(onFloor == true && !animated) {
       jordan1.gotoAndPlay(7);
    }
    if(onFloor == false && !animated) {
        jordan1.gotoAndStop(5);
    }
    animated = true;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rightkeytick);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, rightkeydown);
  }
}
function rightkeydown(e:KeyboardEvent) {
    animated = false;
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, rightkeytick);
    stage.removeEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, rightkeydown);
}
function rightkeytick(e:Event) {
    jordan1.x+=10;
}
```

But you shouldn't use a tick function with a keydown event.

`KEY_DOWN`is called each frame while you're pressing the/a key.

If you can't change your logic (which is not good for what you want to achieve) you could flag your handlers. 
By having a boolean for each key you're listening to.
And then in your tick, do what you need to do depending on what keys are down.

```
keyRight = false;
keyLeft = false;
//... same for all your keys.
// or you could store them in one object for a more dynamic solution.

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,tick);

function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent){
    if(e.keyCode === Keyboard.RIGHT && !keyRight){
        keyRight = true;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === Keyboard.LEFT && !keyLeft){
        keyLeft = true;
    }
    //... same for all your keys.
}

function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent){
    if(e.keyCode === Keyboard.RIGHT){
        keyRight = false;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode === Keyboard.LEFT){
        keyLeft = false;
    }
    //... same for all your keys.
}

function tick(e:Event){
     if(keyRight) jordan1.x += 10;
     if(keyLeft) jordan1.x -= 10;
     //... etc for all your keys.
}
```

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418097/detect-first-key-down-event-only-in-as3) cover the subject of multiple `KEY_DOWN` pretty well.

Comment: Right... add a boolean variable for detecting only first keydown.
Updating my answer.

Comment: Also... after thinking about it. I don't think you need a tick with your keydown event. Or you should remove your keydown listener inside your handler. Else it'll execute while you're pressing the key.

Comment: still not working.Now it doesn't work for either the jump or the animation

Comment: it's too late to change it now.Please can you help me with the animation though. :)

Comment: I've updated my solution for keeping your logic, but having a nicer solution.

Comment: Ok, thank you, but I really need to keep my ticks.Can we do join.me?

Comment: You could keep your ticks with what I did. I'm updating my solution. And I can't join.you for the moment... sorry.

Comment: the problem could be outside of the code I showed you, updated my answer.